# Show messages on the basis of API response in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux

I have installed React using `create-react-app`. I am submitting form using `onSubmit()` function. On submitting form from `LoginRegister.js` Component, below is my LoginRegister.js file code:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import DefaultLayout from '../Layout/DefaultLayout';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { userSignupRequest } from '../actions/signupActions';



class LoginRegister extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {first_name: '',last_name: '',email:'',password:'',c_password:'', phone_no:'',user_role:2, errmsg:''};
        //this.state = {about: ''};

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    

    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
      }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state);
    }   
    
    render(){
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <section id="page-title">

                    <div className="container clearfix">
                        <h1>My Account</h1>
                        <ol className="breadcrumb">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/">Pages</a></li>
                            <li className="active">Login</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>

                </section>

                <section id="content">

                    <div className="content-wrap">

                        <div className="container clearfix">
                            <div className="col_two_third col_last nobottommargin">


                                <h3>Dont have an Account? Register Now.</h3>

                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, vel odio non dicta provident sint ex autem mollitia dolorem illum repellat ipsum aliquid illo similique sapiente fugiat minus ratione.</p>
                                <p id="msg">{this.state.errmsg}</p>
                                <form id="register-form" name="register-form" className="nobottommargin" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                                    <div className="col_half">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-name">First Name:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="register-form-firstname" name="first_name" value={this.state.first_name} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div className="col_half col_last">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-email">Last name:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="register-form-lastname" name="last_name" value={this.state.last_name} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required={true} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="clear"></div>

                                    <div className="col_half">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-email">Email Address:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="register-form-email" name="email" value={this.state.email} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required={true} />
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div className="col_half col_last">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-repassword">Phone no.:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="register-form-phone" name="phone_no" value={this.state.phone_no} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="clear"></div>

                                    <div className="col_half">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-password">Choose Password:</label>
                                        <input type="password" id="register-form-password" name="password" value={this.state.password} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col_half col_last">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-repassword">Re-enter Password:</label>
                                        <input type="password" id="register-form-repassword" name="c_password" value={this.state.c_password} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="user_role" value={this.state.user_role} className="form-control" />  
                                    <div className="clear"></div>

                                    <div className="col_full nobottommargin">
                                        <button className="button button-3d button-black nomargin" id="reg-submit" name="register-form-submit" value="register">Register Now</button>
                                    </div>

                                </form>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </section>
                
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

LoginRegister.propTypes = {
    userSignupRequest: PropTypes.func.isRequired    
}

export default connect((state) => { return{} }, {userSignupRequest} ) (LoginRegister);
```

And action/signupActions file have below code, that calling API and handling response using `Reducer`:

```
import axios from 'axios'; 

export function userSignupRequest(userData){
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch({"type":"CALL_START"});
            axios.post('../user/register', userData).then(response => {
              dispatch({"type":"RECEIVE_RESPONSE", "payload":response.data});
            }).catch(error => {
                dispatch({"type":"RECEIVE_ERROR", "payload":error});
            });
        }
        
    }
```

Reducer.js has the below code:

```
const reducer = (state={}, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "CALL_START" :{
            alert("Hi1");
            return {}
            break;  
        }
        case "RECEIVE_RESPONSE" : {
            //return {...state, data:action.payload}
            alert("Hi2");
            return {data:action.payload}
            break;
        }
        case "RECEIVE_ERROR" : {
            alert("Hi3");
            alert(JSON.stringify(action.payload));
            return {data:action.payload}
            break;
        }
        
    }   
    
}   

export default reducer;
```

API is calling and I am getting response properly. How can I show success/error message on my 'LoginRegister.js' component on the basis of the response?

Comment: Are you using Provider and do you have more reducers that you have combined using combineReducers

Comment: Yes I am using "provider" but ryt now I am not using "combineReducers".

Comment: Can you add your loginRegister code

Comment: one last question, how do you want to display the error or success message and where in the Component exactly

Comment: as normally we show, in an specific div or any html tag. As I am trying to show ryt now in "<p id="msg">". Also want to apply some style on that "p" tag as per message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I will suggest yo uto make a few changes

1. When you use connect then you should probably connect the action to dispatch or directly call it in the component by not providing the second parameter to connect
2. get the state in your component. For this you can make use of mapStateToProps
3. You would probably want to display a proper message on Register, you can do that form the `userSignupRequest` action .

change your code to the below

UserSignUpRequest actions

```
import axios from 'axios'; 

export function userSignupRequest(userData){
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch({"type":"CALL_START"});
            axios.post('../user/register', userData).then(response => {
              dispatch({"type":"RECEIVE_RESPONSE", "payload":"Successfully Registered"});
            }).catch(error => {
                dispatch({"type":"RECEIVE_ERROR", "payload":"Error Registering " +  JSON.stringify(error)});
            });
        }

    }
```

LoginRegister

```
import {bindActionCreators} form 'redux';
class LoginRegister extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {first_name: '',last_name: '',email:'',password:'',c_password:'', phone_no:'',user_role:2, errmsg:''};
        //this.state = {about: ''};

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }


    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
      }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.userSignupRequest({...this.state})
    }   

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.registerMessage)
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <section id="page-title">

                    <div className="container clearfix">
                        <h1>My Account</h1>
                        <ol className="breadcrumb">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/">Pages</a></li>
                            <li className="active">Login</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>

                </section>

                <section id="content">

                    <div className="content-wrap">

                        <div className="container clearfix">
                            <div className="col_two_third col_last nobottommargin">


                                <h3>Dont have an Account? Register Now.</h3>

                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, vel odio non dicta provident sint ex autem mollitia dolorem illum repellat ipsum aliquid illo similique sapiente fugiat minus ratione.</p>
                                <p id="msg">{this.props.registerMessage}</p>
                                <form id="register-form" name="register-form" className="nobottommargin" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                                    <div className="col_half">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-name">First Name:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="register-form-firstname" name="first_name" value={this.state.first_name} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col_half col_last">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-email">Last name:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="register-form-lastname" name="last_name" value={this.state.last_name} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required={true} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="clear"></div>

                                    <div className="col_half">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-email">Email Address:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="register-form-email" name="email" value={this.state.email} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required={true} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col_half col_last">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-repassword">Phone no.:</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="register-form-phone" name="phone_no" value={this.state.phone_no} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="clear"></div>

                                    <div className="col_half">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-password">Choose Password:</label>
                                        <input type="password" id="register-form-password" name="password" value={this.state.password} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col_half col_last">
                                        <label htmlFor="register-form-repassword">Re-enter Password:</label>
                                        <input type="password" id="register-form-repassword" name="c_password" value={this.state.c_password} className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="user_role" value={this.state.user_role} className="form-control" />  
                                    <div className="clear"></div>

                                    <div className="col_full nobottommargin">
                                        <button className="button button-3d button-black nomargin" id="reg-submit" name="register-form-submit" value="register">Register Now</button>
                                    </div>

                                </form>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </section>

            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){
      return { 
         registerMessage: state.data
      }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({userSignupRequest: userSignupRequest}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps ) (LoginRegister);
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = { 
    data: '',
    status: ''
}
const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type){
case "CALL_START" :{
alert("Hi1");
return {}
break; 
}
case "RECEIVE_RESPONSE" : {
//return {...state, data:action.payload}
return {...state, data:action.payload}
break;
}
case "RECEIVE_ERROR" : {
alert(JSON.stringify(action.payload));
return { ...state, data:action.payload}
break;
}
default: {
return state
}
} 

} 

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Let me know if you need more clarifications or help

Comment: Its giving this error on cosole -
>>>>>>>>>>>>> LoginRegister.js:198 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at Function.exports.default.userSignupRequest [as mapToProps] (LoginRegister.js:198)>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Line 198 is  - >>>>>>export default connect((state) => { return{ registerMessage: state.data} }, {userSignupRequest} ) (LoginRegister);

Comment: Make sure that you wrap the component within a provider like 
`<Provider store={store}>{/* component here */}</Provider>` and try the updated answer

Comment: still showing the same error, n also showing warning - >>warning  'userSignupRequest' is defined but never used......
And where I need to do this  - >>> <Provider store={store}>{/* component here */}</Provider>

Comment: Use provider in index.js, also check connect function I have removed usersignuprequest from there

Comment: In index.js file I have already set it ...plz check  ->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`ReactDOM.render(( 
     <Provider store={store}>
       <Router>
      <switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
       <Route path="/Loginregister" component={Login} />
      </switch>
       </Router>
     </Provider>  ),
      document.getElementById('wrapper')
    );`

Comment: Atul your switch component doesn't being with upper case, and I am assuming your have imported reducer and created a store as well

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanx this helped me alot

Answer (score 2):

> But here I don't know how to show success/error message on my 'LoginRegister.js' component on th basis of response

Subscribe to the state using `@connect`.

## More

- http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: I have already applied  on LoginRegister.js ------ 

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

this.state = {errmsg:''};

and this below end of file........................
export default connect((state) => { return{} }, {userSignupRequest} ) (LoginRegister); ..................I am setting --->>>this.setState({errmsg: "Hello to all........."}); on reducer.js file but that not updating over LoginRegister.js...................